# Self Join in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, self-join

I have a table, P, with a personid column and licensetypeid column.

Each person can have multiple license types, adding additional rows to the table for that person ID.

I need to find the rows where personid has both licenseid of 1 and of 5.

I can't write:

```
SELECT personid, licensetypeid 
FROM P 
WHERE licensetypeid=1 AND licensetypeid=5;
```

I heard I should use a self-join to do this. How do I do a self join to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Self-joins and other techniques of accessing the table more than once will work, but may reduce performance and are unwieldy if you need to generalize to larger sets of ids.

You can do it with a single reference to the table by counting the number of matching rows per person:

```
select personid from P
  where licensetypeid in ('1','5')
  group by personid
  having count(*) = 2
```

This can easily be expanded if you want to require a larger licensetypeid values:

```
select personid from P
  where licensetypeid in ('1','5','7')
  group by personid
  having count(*) = 3
```

(in the self-join version you would have to add an additional join for each additional value)

Or if you want to find people that have at least 2 types out of a larger set of types:

```
select personid from P
  where licensetypeid in ('1','5', '7', '10')
  group by personid
  having count(*) >= 2
```

Now, unlike your sample query, the licensetypeid is not included in the result set.  If that is necessary for some reason, you can do a simple trick in the case of 2 values:

```
select personid, min(licensetypeid) licensetype1, max(licensetypeid) licensetype2
  from P
  where licensetypeid in ('1','5')
  group by personid
  having count(*) = 2
```

But a more general approach is to group the values into a simple collection:

```
select personid, collect(licensetypeid) licensetypeidlist
  from P
  where licensetypeid in ('1','5')
  group by personid
  having count(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select personid, licensetypeid
from P P1
where exists (
   select 1
   from P P2
   where P2.personid = P1.personid
      and P2.licensetypeid = 1
) and exists (
   select 1
   from P P2
   where P2.personid = P1.personid
      and P2.licensetypeid = 5
)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. But I am confussed. What is this P1? Is that table the table name used in the query? Can you please expalin

Comment: Sorry, syntax error there, I have edited the answer "P P1" etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT distinct
       p1.personid
      ,p1.licensetypeid 
      ,p2.licensetypeid
from P p1, P p2
WHERE p1.personid = p2.personid
AND   p1.licensetypeid = 1
AND   p2.licensetypeid = 5
;
```

Comment: Hi this one is working I guess. Thanks for the post.. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select personid,licensetypeid from P where licensetypeid in ('1','5')
```

Comment: . Thanks for the answer .No it will take the entries which have licenseid 1 or 5. I need to get the personid who has both the license

Comment: @Remya Is this 1 and 5 is constant or is it dynamic like it can be 1,5 (as in your case) or sometimes 1 only or sometimes 1,2,5?

Comment: yeah its like some employee can have license 1 only some can have 5 only and some have both. I need the employee with both the license.but the license id is constant(1,5 etc)

Comment: -1: shows any person that has either license type, not those persons that have both

Answer (score 0):

If your set of required license types is "fixed", or at least if the cardinality of the set of required license types is fixed, then the given answers will work OK.

Otherwise, you need to write the SQL equivalent of what is known as "relational division".

That goes as follows:

(1) Compute the set of persons that LACK at least one of the required license types :

```
SELECT personid 
from P 
WHERE EXISTS
  (
    SELECT licenseid 
    from NEEDEDLICENSETYPE AS NLT 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT * 
      FROM P AS PBIS 
      WHERE 
        PBIS.personid = P.personid AND
        PBIS.licensetype = NLT.licensetype
    )
  )
```

NEEDELICENSETYPE represents whatever SQL statement you need to compute the set of required license types on a particular invocation.

(2) Select the data for the persons with a number that does not appear in (1) :

```
SELECT ... FROM P WHERE personid NOT IN (...)
```

Comment: sorry for the off-topic question, but do you create a new user for each answer you give or is "Erwin Smout" just a really common name in some country? ;-)